# horizontal website anchors

Tags: javascript, scroll, alignment

i am working on a site that scrolls horizontally. before i put the jquery scroll.to plugin in, i have some work that needs to be ironed out with the anchors.

you can see [in the example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2852501/help/siteDesign.html), when you click to go to box 2, it doesn't go to the right location. then when you click back to box 1 or home, it's placed the content flush to the left side.

this is very similar to [a previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516562/horizontal-content-scrolling-to-anchors-how-do-you-center-the-anchors) question, but it's not answered.

Comment: the way i solved this was i put in "fake anchors". it doesn't scroll to the actual box, but to an invisible point that i want it to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can see this. This is working great. You can see the source code and try. It is using jquery plugin to smooth scroll.

[SEE THIS](http://work.9lessons.info/horizontalsite/)

Comment: i had trouble finding a solution from that demo. it's good though.